# Как сделать редирект с любого поддомена на основной домен?

Tags: .htaccess, редирект

Нужно с любого несуществующего поддомена (*123123.site.com*, или *qwe111.site.com*, или **.site.com*) сделать редирект `301` на основной домен.

Пробую через *htaccess*:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks   
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+).site.com$   
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://www.site.com/$1 [R=301,NC]
```

С поддоменов попадает на страницу *it works*, а не на *index.php*. Просто *site.com* работает как надо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

скорее всего, дефолтный *virtualhost* у вас настроен на совершенно другой *documentroot*. но это несущественно ввиду того, что проще вообще не указывать в нём *documentroot*. примерно так:

```
<virtualhost *:80>
  redirect permanent / http://www.site.com/
</virtualhost>
```

а в основном *virtualhost-е* не забудьте указать `www.site.com`:

```
<virtualhost *:80>
  servername www.site.ru
  ...
</virtualhost>
```

то, что вы написали в `.htaccess`, не нужно: управление ведь всё равно не попадает в тот *documentroot*, в котором этот файл находится.

Comment: никакого эффекта

Comment: редирект, как я понял, всё-таки происходит. если да, то почему вы делаете редирект на `www.site.com`,  а не на `site.com`? у вас точно прописан приём трафика для `www.site.com`?

Comment: я обновил ответ.

Comment: при наборе 111.site.com или www.111.site.com или http://www.111.site.com никакой разницы - it works

Comment: я обновил ответ. попробуйте сделать так, как в нём написано.

Comment: в настройках апача нет дефолтных настроек виртуального хоста - только под каждый сервер. добавил строчку:    Redirect permanent / http://www.site.com/ (без / отказывалось работать - неправильный редирект) - не помогло. откуда берется it works для меня загадка

Comment: *С поддоменов попадает на страницу it works* — скорее всего, это и выдаёт дефолтный *virtualhost*. но если его **точно** нет, то просто добавьте те три строки, что подсказаны в ответе. если же всё-таки есть — закомментируйте или удалите существующие и вставьте эти самые три строки.

Comment: нашел дефолтные настройки - теперь получилось. но получилось со /

Comment: @Prog2010, прошу прощения, я допустил опечатку в ответе: у директивы *redirect* должен быть ещё один аргумент (в данном случае *слэш*). я исправил ответ.